# Is there any way concurrency can be achieved between java and native code? With native code running as a process/thread

Tags: java, concurrency, java-native-interface, ipc

How do we go about running a native process and java process concurrently with both of them sharing certain elements to help send/receive data.

Answer (score 0):

If they are different processes, better do not share anything directly, but connect them via TCP/IP. Let one of them be a server and another a client.

If you really need to share, put both native and java parts in the same process. Traditional way is to make java part the main one, and add native part as a library. But opposite way to load JVM as a library is also possible:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html.